# Replacing custom template who contain deprecated unary function

Tags: c++, c++17, deprecated

I want to upgrade my visual studio program, to the C++latsest.
And as i see unary_function was removed.

That's my actual code where i use unary

```
namespace std
{
template <class _Ty>
class void_mem_fun_t: public unary_function<_Ty*, void>
{
public:
    explicit void_mem_fun_t(void (_Ty::*_Pm)()): _Ptr(_Pm)
    {
    }
    void operator()(_Ty* _P) const
    {
        ((_P->*_Ptr)());
    }
private:
    void (_Ty::*_Ptr)();
};

template<class _Ty> inline
void_mem_fun_t<_Ty> void_mem_fun(void (_Ty::*_Pm)())
{
    return (void_mem_fun_t<_Ty>(_Pm));
}

}
```

It's a custom implementation.
And the usage :

```
for_each(
    OneVector.begin(),
    OneVector.end(),
    std::void_mem_fun(&SomeClass::UseFunc)
);
```

Can i use lambda as a replacement? Or what it's your advice?
I need an example about lambda usage.

Comment: You never needed `void_mem_fun_t`. `std::mem_fn(&SomeClass::UseFunc)` is fine (you need to specify which `UseFunc` if is overloaded)

Comment: Simply use `for (const auto& e: OneVector) { e.UseFunc(); }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"It's a custom implementation."* - Strictly speaking, you aren't allowed to add names into namespace `std`. That leaves you officially with undefined behavior. So it's a bad idea even before upgrading.

Since you upgraded, either use `std::mem_fn`, or if you insist on the lambda solution:

```
for_each(
    OneVector.begin(),
    OneVector.end(),
    [](auto *s) { return s->UseFunc(); } )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the code correctly, all you'd need to do is use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) instead of your `void_mem_fun` (and can thus drop the class template too).

After `auto a = std::mem_fn(&C::foo)`, `a` is a callable object which accepts an argument of type `C*` or `C&` and calls `foo` on it.